# Is this an ambiguous use of the symbol $\Rightarrow$

Tags: logic, soft-question, notation

The notation $A \Rightarrow B$ can mean that $A \rightarrow B$ is a tautology. For example $\neg A \vee C \Rightarrow A \rightarrow (B \vee C)$. The question is whether it is possible to have $A \Rightarrow B$ or not. The reason why I am asking is that I saw an expression, which in my mind applies two different meanings to the symbol '$\Rightarrow$', namely that of implication ($\rightarrow$) and that of logical truth ($\Rightarrow$). I do not remember the exact expression, but it looked something like this:

$[(A \Rightarrow B) \vee \neg B] \Rightarrow \neg A$

I think what is meant is this:

$[(A \rightarrow B) \vee \neg B] \Rightarrow \neg A$

However I could be wrong. However the question is that you are supposed to show that the expression is tautological with the help of a truth table. So I think the expression $[(A \Rightarrow B) \vee \neg B] \Rightarrow \neg A$ ascribes two different meanings to the symbol '$\Rightarrow$'. **The question**: Is this an ambiguous use of the symbol '$\Rightarrow$' or is it correct to write $[(A \Rightarrow B) \vee \neg B] \Rightarrow \neg A$ with the context I provided?

Comment: We have two notions in play: the *connective* "if___, then___" and the relation of *(logical) implication*; they are different but strictly linked. We have not a universally agreed convention. We can use $P \to Q$ to write a propositional formula (read: "if $P$, the $Q$") and $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ for the meta-logical relation : the formula $\varphi$ implies the formula $\psi$ (also : $\varphi \vDash \psi$). I strongly suggest : do **not** use the same symbol with both meanings in the same context

Comment: Given that some authors like to use $\Rightarrow$ for the logical connective, a logician who would use it instead of $\vdash$ or $\vDash$ should be publicly censured...